# Build the dataframe with conditional vector in R

Tags: r

I have two vectors

```
a <- c(18,19,19,19,21,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,30,31,35,36,37)
b <- c(19,25,31,37)
```

I need the data frame following format:

```
a      b
18     19
19     19
19     19
19     19
21     25
21     25
22     25
23     25
24     25
25     25
26     31
27     31
28     31 
30     31
31     31
35     37
36     37
37     37
```

Here  value 19 in vector `b` repeat up to the value 19 in vector `a`.
After that 21(in a) is the greater than 19 ,so the next value of 25(in b) is be repeat until the 25(in a )
in similar way construct the dataframe.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can get the position index from `findInterval`, use that to create the `times` for the `rep`

```
i1 <- findInterval(b, a)
data.frame(a, b = rep(b, c(i1[1], diff(i1))))
#    a  b
#1  18 19
#2  19 19
#3  19 19
#4  19 19
#5  21 25
#6  21 25
#7  22 25
#8  23 25
#9  24 25
#10 25 25
#11 26 31
#12 27 31
#13 28 31
#14 30 31
#15 31 31
#16 35 37
#17 36 37
#18 37 37
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively,

```
data.frame(a, b = sapply(a, function(x) b[x <= b][1]))
#     a  b
# 1  18 19
# 2  19 19
# 3  19 19
# 4  19 19
# 5  21 25
# 6  21 25
# 7  22 25
# 8  23 25
# 9  24 25
# 10 25 25
# 11 26 31
# 12 27 31
# 13 28 31
# 14 30 31
# 15 31 31
# 16 35 37
# 17 36 37
# 18 37 37
```

Comment: @ Julius could you explain the `[1]` term.

Comment: @user7462639, as to get the `b` column, I go over `a` and look for all such `b` that are greater of equal than a particular element element of `a`: `b[x <= b]`. Then, assuming that `b` is an ordered vector, I add `[1]` to take the smallest `b` satisfying that condition.

Comment: @ Julius Thank you.for explanation.